# UITableViewCell Style Causes Illegal Configuration Error

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

I have a UITableViewCell, and if I set its style to anything other than Custom, it gives me the following design-time error:

```
Illegal Configuration
Only the "Custom" style is supported in versions prior to Xcode 4.2
```

It will still compile and run fine though.

I'm using Xcode 4.2 (build 4D199), so I don't understand why it is saying this. Furthermore, I can't find anything on the web about this, which makes me suspicious that it's something particular to my setup.

I can duplicate it by creating a new Xcode project and just dropping a UITableViewCell on the designer and setting its style to something other than Basic. If somebody could do this real quick to see if it happens to them, even that might help because then I'd at least know if it's just my setup.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It does not run fine: It seems to cause an exception when run on iOS 3.1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No biggie. This warning is thrown just in case you'll want to open your project in <4.2 interface builder versions. Open your cell's xib and see the development versioning settings (pic bellow)

[image]

From the deployment/development drop-downs select the latest Xcode version and warning should go away.